# yii jui datepicker not showing correct date on update page

Tags: php, date, yii2

I am using the following datepicker code in my form..the date is saving correctly in the database but in the update page the date is being displayed as '01.1970' in the field..but when i change it and save , it is correctly stored in the database..but the field display on edit is always 01.1970

```
<?= $form->field($model,'apartment_year_build')->widget(DatePicker::className(),[ 'dateFormat' => 'MM.yyyy', 'clientOptions' => [
                        'changeMonth' => true,
                        'yearRange' => '1989:2099',
                'changeYear' => true,
                        'firstDay' =>'1',
                        // 'showOn' => 'button',
                        // 'buttonImage' => 'images/calendar.gif',
                        // 'buttonImageOnly' => true,
                        // 'buttonText' => 'Select date' >

                    ],'options'=>['class'=>'form-control']]) ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have 01.1970 this mean that mysql (or php?)  working on a wrong date content. (1/1/1970 is the equivalent fo null date)

Check in your db if the value is correctly saved ..

if you need  a format like 02.2016 your format should be

```
    [ 'dateFormat' => 'php:m.Y',....
```

Comment: the values are saved correctly in db..like 12.2012 and when echoed gives the correct value..but only in the update form page the field value is 01.1970

Comment: Only in update form you (correct value) from db is display by the format you used .. could be  formatting issue.. have you tried changing format .. i have update the answer

Comment: i tried the format you gave..but the issue still exist..everything works fine..saving in db and displaying in view all works correctly as the stored db value..but on the update page in the datepicker field the value is 01.1970 when loaded

Comment: Are you sure that the m.Y format is supported  b y datePicker .. ?  Just for debug try other valid formats